# How will the new Oxford "Academy of English" appoint its members?

Tags: international

The new Oxford Academy, announced yesterday, we are told will draw members from around the world. Mirroring the *Academie Francaise* it expects to become the authoritative guide to spoken and written English within five years.

How exactly will it select its academicians?

Just been announced, it's to be given Royal Academy status, comparable to the Royal Academies of Science, Music, Art, Dramatic Art etc. They will be given the designatory letters RAL -Royal Academy of Letters, for use after their names. (RAE was not available due to possible confusion with the Royal Aircraft Establishment)

So they will be known as Royal Academicians and appointed by the Queen and her successors. But the question remains, how will they be selected?

Harvard, Yale, Princeton, Monash (Australia), and all the Russell Group Universities in Britain are to grant accreditation and recognition of the leading role of Oxford in this venture, in view of the existing status, staff and resources, of the Oxford English Dictionary.

Commentators say the most surprising thing of all is that recognition has been received from Cambridge.

Comment: It's off-topic, and one of them will be FumbleFingers.

Comment: @JohnClifford - I bet one of them will be you!

Comment: @Josh61 Nah, I'm just good enough at finding definitions and waffling that people think I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Actually, yeah, now that you mention it that makes me a perfect candidate for a bureaucratic authority on English.

Comment: There already is an Oxford Academy, and it's a high school in a not particularly salubrious area of the city just down the road from where I live. 'Academy' in the UK is a word definitely *not* imbued with anything like the sense of its French counterpart.

Comment: @CharlE The name is only provisional for the moment, and they are going to run a competition to come up with a better one? Any ideas? I fancy we may get a lot of Boaty McBoat-Faces! [This is the site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy%20oxford) which tells you all about it.

Comment: @JohnClifford I think it should definitely be regarded as on-topic as it could put sites like this into extinction.

Comment: @WS2 - into extinction.. why?

Comment: @Josh61 What's correct and not correct will become a matter beyond debate, once the academy has spoken.

Comment: @WS2 Surely all that's going to mean is that when people post questions here we'll have a unified, definitive resource to link our answers to.

Comment: @JohnClifford Could get a bit boring though!

Comment: @WS2 This site will become more precious than ever before, as we end up having to endlessly explain to people that grammar is what  people do when they speak.

Comment: It appears to have less staying power than the spaghetti harvest.

Comment: @WS2 That link is broken, and googling turns nothing up. Is this an April Fool's joke? Are you sure the article you read wasn't an April Fool's joke?

Comment: Oh, you crafty devil you. I almost fell for it  until that bit about being appointed by the Queen.

Comment: The Spaghetti Harvest : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tVo_wkxH9dU

Comment: @Josh61 I was twelve years old when the Spaghetti Harvest first went out on BBC TV. I don't think I saw it at the time, and by the time I did, was aware that it was a hoax. (In those days the British did not eat dubious foreign foods). Richard Dimbleby was the presenter, father of David and Jonathan Dimbleby, still at the centre of BBC political affairs - even though both are well into their seventies. Somehow I cannot imagine the BBC without a Dimbleby - but there is no third generation coming along.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is too localised.

Comment: @waiwai933 I wouldn't expect a Cambridge person like you to suggest differently. But if it's any consolation to you, when it comes to Oxford and Cambridge, my own loyalties are with the Light Blues.